# Does MCPE have golems?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Have golems been added to Minecraft Pocket edition? I haven't played it in a while.

Answer (score 6):

Minecraft Pocket Edition has both Snow golems and Iron golems.

[image: An iron and a snow golem in Vanilla MCPE]

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can make snow golems and iron golems. To make a iron golem make a small T with 4 iron blocks and then add a pumpkin to the top-middle. To make a snow golem place 2 snow blocks upwards and then a pumpkin on top. I hope this has helped you and have a good day